# vpn service that use akamai servers

Tags: vpn, akamai

is it possible to host a vpn or a proxy on akamai servers and is there any available vpn services that host it servers on akamai 
I tried googling but it throw in another whole direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rahim, As far as i am aware akamai doesn't host vpn servers, but there are other CDN providers which do provide this feature.

If you are looking something within akamai then i suggest you contact the customer care, even though vpn server hosting might not be available but they will guide if you there are other approaches within akamai that you can use.

Comment: Akamai now provides "Secure Application Access" which is close to what you are looking for i believe: https://www.akamai.com/uk/en/solutions/why-akamai/secure-application-access.jsp

Answer (score 0):

akamai doesn't do hosting at all, only CDN and cloud computing